# React change react component state from global JS function file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So let's say I have this global JS function file that other components use to make rest calls, if the response is unauthorized I want it to change the state of a React component to loggedIn:false. Is this possible?

Comment: I would recomend looking into redux if you want to control state.

Comment: share a minimal code example?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a use case of redux. You will maintain **loggedIn** in your store and connect whichever component requires this info with the store.

Else there are two other ways not that good which I will call hacks.
1) Maintain this in url query params and read the params in component.
2) Maintain this in sessionStorage or localStorage.
3) Maintain it in window.isLoggedIn

But since this is login related info I would avoid using these ways. For some other global, you can use above mentioned ways.

Take a look at redux here
https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact

Answer (score 0):

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
...
  async getData() {
    await response = fnToGetData();
    if (response.unauthorized) {
      this.props.setAuthorizationStatus(false);
      // or if you want to set authorization only in this component
      // this.setState(() => ({authorized: false}));

    } else {
      // do sth with the data
    }
  }
}
```

Where `setAuthorizationStatus` lives somewhere on top of your app and is passed down through props (you can also use context to pass it down conveniently).